# Upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS fails due to `Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu`

Tags: 18.04, package-management, upgrade, 20.04

When trying to upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS on my PC, the process fails due to `Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu`. I tried to find the broken packages using `grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` and I got this:

```
Broken python:amd64 PreDepends on python-minimal:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii pgR > (= 2.7.15~rc1-1)
Broken python-pkg-resources:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-six:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-chardet:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-gtk2:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-gobject-2:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-cairo:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-lxml:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-html5lib:amd64 Depends on python-pkg-resources:amd64 < 39.0.1-2 @ii mR >
Broken python-pyqt5:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken samba-common-bin:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR >
Broken python-bs4:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-routes:amd64 Depends on python-six:amd64 < 1.11.0-2 @ii mR >
Broken python-pil:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python3-crypto:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python-libxml2:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-simplejson:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken onboard:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken libc6-dbg:amd64 Depends on libc6:amd64 < 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 -> 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 @ii umU IPb > (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.2)
Broken python3-reportlab-accel:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python-dbus:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python3-protobuf:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python-gi:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken libldb2:amd64 Breaks on libldb1:amd64 < 2:1.2.3-1ubuntu0.1 @ii mK > (< 2:2~)
Broken python3-zope.interface:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python3-renderpm:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken p11-kit-modules:amd64 Depends on libp11-kit0:amd64 < 0.23.9-2 -> 0.23.20-1build1 @ii umU > (= 0.23.9-2)
Broken python3-netifaces:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python-rpm:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-crypto:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-markdown:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-tdb:amd64 Depends on libtdb1:amd64 < 1.3.15-2 -> 1.4.2-3build1 @ii umU > (= 1.3.15-2)
Broken python-asn1crypto:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-olefile:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-ipaddress:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python3-pycurl:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python-webencodings:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-cryptography:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-cssutils:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-sqlitecachec:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
Broken python-reportlab-accel:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-pyqt5.qtsvg:amd64 Depends on python-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 @ii mR > (= 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2)
Broken python-pycurl:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-webob:amd64 Depends on python-simplejson:amd64 < 3.13.2-1 @ii mR >
Broken python-sqlite:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (>= 2.7)
Broken python-dnspython:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-regex:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python3-pyqt5:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python-cssselect:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR >
Broken python-utidylib:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-feedparser:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-urlgrabber:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-renderpm:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-netifaces:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python3-cffi-backend:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python-samba:amd64 Depends on python-crypto:amd64 < 2.6.1-8ubuntu2 @ii mR >
Broken python-cherrypy3:amd64 Depends on python-six:amd64 < 1.11.0-2 @ii mR >
Broken onboard-data:amd64 Depends on onboard:amd64 < 1.4.1-2ubuntu1 @ii mR > (< 1.4.1-2ubuntu1.1)
Broken python-glade2:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-apsw:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-repoze.lru:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-pygments:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-lzma:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-enum34:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-openssl:amd64 Depends on python-cryptography:amd64 < 2.1.4-1ubuntu1.3 @ii mR > (>= 2.1.4)
Broken python-distutils-extra:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-msgpack:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-mechanize:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
Broken python-html5-parser:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-pyparsing:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken python-yaml:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken libgnutls-openssl27:amd64 Depends on libgnutls30:amd64 < 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.4 -> 3.6.13-2ubuntu1.3 @ii umU > (= 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.4)
Broken python-pyqt5.qtwebkit:amd64 Depends on python-pyqt5:amd64 < 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 @ii mR > (= 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2)
Broken python-idna:amd64 Depends on python:any:any < none @un H > (< 2.8)
Broken calibre:amd64 Depends on python-dbus:amd64 < 1.2.6-1 @ii mR >
Broken python-dateutil:amd64 Depends on python-six:amd64 < 1.11.0-2 @ii mR > (>= 1.5)
Broken python-ldb:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-notify:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (>= 2.7)
Broken python3-sip:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken hplip-gui:amd64 Depends on python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5:amd64 < 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 @ii mR >
Broken fluendo-eula:amd64 Depends on python-gtk2:amd64 < 2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2 @ii mR >
Broken python-cffi-backend:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-reportlab:amd64 Depends on python-pil:amd64 < 5.1.0-1ubuntu0.3 @ii mR >
Broken gimp:amd64 Depends on python-gtk2:amd64 < 2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2 @ii mR > (>= 2.8.0)
Broken python-sip:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-dev:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (= 2.7.15~rc1-1)
Broken python-gobject:amd64 Depends on python-gi:amd64 < 3.26.1-2ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 3.26.1-2ubuntu1)
Broken gwakeonlan:amd64 Depends on python-gtk2:amd64 < 2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2 @ii mR > (>= 2.12)
Broken yum:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (>= 2.7)
Broken python-qt4:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken python-qt4-dbus:amd64 Depends on python-dbus:amd64 < 1.2.6-1 @ii mR > (>= 0.84.0-2~)
Broken python3-gi:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python3-dbus:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python3-apt:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken libc6-dev:amd64 Depends on libc6:amd64 < 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 -> 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 @ii umU IPb > (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.2)
Broken libglib2.0-bin:amd64 Depends on libglib2.0-0:amd64 < 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 -> 2.64.3-1~ubuntu20.04.1 @ii umU > (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 -> 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5 @ii umU Ib > (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20)
Broken libtext-iconv-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken python3-cups:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken libnet-dbus-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken liblocale-gettext-perl:amd64 PreDepends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libhtml-parser-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python3-cairo:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken rhythmbox-plugins:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken libsocket6-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libglib-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken python3-pil:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on libwbclient0:amd64 < 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 -> 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5 @ii umU Ib > (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20)
Broken python3-yaml:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken libfile-fcntllock-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on libgjs0-libmozjs-52-0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libxml-parser-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken python3-gi-cairo:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python3-systemd:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python3-lxml:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken libnet-ssleay-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libgail-3-0:amd64 Depends on libgtk-3-0:amd64 < 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 -> 3.24.20-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.22.30-1ubuntu4)
Broken libc6-i386:amd64 Depends on libc6:amd64 < 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 -> 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 @ii umU IPb > (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.2)
Broken libnet-libidn-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libreoffice-math:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 -> 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umU Ib > (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10)
Broken libtext-charwidth-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libcairo-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken totem-plugins:amd64 Depends on libtotem0:amd64 < 3.26.0-0ubuntu6.2 -> 3.34.1-2ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.27)
Broken python3-nacl:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken libcairo-gobject-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken python3-simplejson:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python3-markupsafe:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken python3-brlapi:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.6.7-1~18.04 -> 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 @ii umU > (< 3.7)
Broken cups-ipp-utils:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken samba-common-bin:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 | 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5 @ii umR > (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5)
Broken libyaml-libyaml-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libclone-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libxml-libxml-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3:amd64 Breaks on uno-libs3:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 @ii mK >
Broken libio-pty-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken python3-samba:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 | 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5 @ii umR > (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5)
Broken libsub-name-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 -> 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umU Ib > (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10)
Broken libuno-cppu3:amd64 Breaks on uno-libs3:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 @ii mK >
Broken cups-bsd:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken libuno-sal3:amd64 Breaks on uno-libs3:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 @ii mK >
Broken libsensors-config:amd64 Conflicts on libsensors4:amd64 < 1:3.4.0-4 @ii mK >
Broken libreoffice-pdfimport:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-common:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 -> 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umU Ib > (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10)
Broken libreoffice-gtk3:amd64 Depends on libuno-cppu3:amd64 < none | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH > (>= 4.4.0~alpha)
Broken libcups2-dev:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < none | 2:2.0.10-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @un uH > (= 2:2.0.10-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken uno-libs-private:amd64 Depends on libuno-cppu3:amd64 < none | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH > (>= 1.4.0)
Broken libreoffice-style-breeze:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-common:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 -> 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umU Ib > (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 Breaks on gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu1.3 @ii mK > (< 3.30.1.2-2~)
Broken liblist-moreutils-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libuno-salhelpergcc3-3:amd64 Depends on libuno-sal3:amd64 < none | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH > (>= 1.8.0)
Broken libreoffice-style-galaxy:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-common:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 -> 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umU Ib > (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10)
Broken libapt-pkg-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3:amd64 Depends on uno-libs-private:amd64 < none | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken libuuid-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libfcgi-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libperlio-gzip-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libapparmor-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken calibre-bin:amd64 Depends on sip-api-12.3:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libpango-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libreoffice-gtk2:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 -> 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umU Ib > (= 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10)
Broken libpango1.0-0:amd64 Depends on libpango-1.0-0:amd64 < 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 -> 1.44.7-2ubuntu4 @ii umU > (= 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1)
Broken libdata-alias-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.1:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken libgtk2-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.26.0:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken python-sip:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken libreoffice-gtk:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-gtk2:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 @ii mR >
Broken ure:amd64 Depends on uno-libs-private:amd64 < none | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken ibus:amd64 Depends on gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 < 1.5.17-3ubuntu5.3 -> 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1 @ii umU > (= 1.5.17-3ubuntu5.3)
Broken gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH > (= 3.36.1-0ubuntu1)
Broken libreoffice-core:amd64 Depends on ure:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 6.1.1~)
Broken cups:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken libcupsppdc1:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken cups-ppdc:amd64 Depends on libcupsppdc1:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 @ii mR > (>= 1.4.0)
Broken libcupsmime1:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken libsmbclient:amd64 Depends on samba-libs:amd64 < 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 | 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5 @ii umR > (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20)
Broken libcupscgi1:amd64 Depends on libcups2:amd64 < 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8 -> 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 @ii umU > (= 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8)
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core-nogui:amd64 < none @un H > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on libuno-cppu3:amd64 < none | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH > (>= 4.4.0~alpha)
Broken samba-libs:amd64 Depends on libwbclient0:amd64 < 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 -> 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5 @ii umU Ib > (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20)
Broken libedata-book-1.2-25:amd64 Depends on libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 < 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3)
Broken libnss-systemd:amd64 Depends on systemd:amd64 < 237-3ubuntu10.42 -> 245.4-4ubuntu3.2 @ii umU > (= 237-3ubuntu10.42)
Broken libedata-cal-1.2-28:amd64 Depends on libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 < 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3)
Broken gnome-shell:amd64 Depends on gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 < 1.5.17-3ubuntu5.3 | 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1 @ii umH > (>= 1.5.22-2ubuntu2~)
Broken libebook-1.2-19:amd64 Depends on libedata-book-1.2-25:amd64 < 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 @ii mR > (= 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.3)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken libreoffice-math:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken libreoffice-base-core:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken libreoffice-base-core:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core-nogui:amd64 < none @un H > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken libreoffice-base-core:amd64 Depends on libuno-cppu3:amd64 < none | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @un uH > (>= 4.4.0~alpha)
Broken libreoffice-impress:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken libreoffice-draw:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken libreoffice-writer:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-base-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-appindicator:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR > (>= 3.33)
Broken libreoffice-calc:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-base-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken libreoffice-gnome:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (= 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
Broken gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR > (< 3.37)
Broken libsensors5:amd64 Depends on libsensors-config:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken gdm3:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR > (>= 3.19.92)
Broken libmutter-6-0:amd64 Breaks on gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu1.3 | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 3.31.91)
Broken libreoffice-ogltrans:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-impress:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umR > (>= 1:6.2.0~beta1~)
Broken calibre-bin:amd64 Depends on sip-api-12.3:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gdm3:amd64 < 3.28.3-0ubuntu18.04.4 | 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umR >
Broken python-sip:amd64 Depends on python:amd64 < 2.7.15~rc1-1 @ii mR > (< 2.8)
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
Broken libreoffice-common:amd64 Breaks on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (< 1:6.4.2~rc1)
Broken libreoffice-core:amd64 Depends on ure:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 6.1.1~)
Broken ubuntu-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-shell:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.3 | 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 @ii umR > (>= 3.24.3-0ubuntu2)
Broken aspell:amd64 Depends on libaspell15:amd64 < 0.60.7~20110707-4ubuntu0.1 -> 0.60.8-1build1 @ii umU > (= 0.60.7~20110707-4ubuntu0.1)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken libsnmp35:amd64 Depends on libsensors5:amd64 < none | 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1 @un uH > (>= 1:3.5.0)
Broken gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 Depends on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < none | 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 @un uH > (= 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2)
Broken calibre-bin:amd64 Depends on sip-api-12.3:amd64 < none @un H >
Broken unity-session:amd64 Depends on gnome-session-bin:amd64 < 3.28.1-0ubuntu3 -> 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 @ii umU > (< 3.29)
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
Broken librsvg2-common:amd64 Depends on librsvg2-2:amd64 < 2.40.20-2ubuntu0.2 -> 2.48.7-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umU > (= 2.40.20-2ubuntu0.2)
Broken libreoffice-common:amd64 Breaks on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (< 1:6.4.2~rc1)
Broken libreoffice-core:amd64 Depends on ure:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 6.1.1~)
Broken libhpmud0:amd64 Depends on libsnmp35:amd64 < none | 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3 @un uH > (>= 5.8+dfsg)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libhpmud0:amd64 < 3.17.10+repack0-5 | 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 @ii umH > (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2)
Broken printer-driver-postscript-hp:amd64 Depends on hplip:amd64 < 3.17.10+repack0-5 | 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 @ii umR > (>= 3.17.10+repack0-5)
Broken printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 Depends on libhpmud0:amd64 < 3.17.10+repack0-5 | 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 @ii umH > (>= 3.20.3+dfsg0)
Broken libsane-hpaio:amd64 Depends on libhpmud0:amd64 < 3.17.10+repack0-5 | 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 @ii umH > (>= 3.20.3+dfsg0)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken eog:amd64 Depends on librsvg2-2:amd64 < 2.40.20-2ubuntu0.2 | 2.48.7-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 2.44)
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
Broken libreoffice-common:amd64 Breaks on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (< 1:6.4.2~rc1)
Broken libreoffice-core:amd64 Depends on ure:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 6.1.1~)
Broken gnome-session-common:amd64 Breaks on eog:amd64 < 3.28.1-1 | 3.36.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 3.36.0)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken eog:amd64 Depends on librsvg2-2:amd64 < 2.40.20-2ubuntu0.2 | 2.48.7-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 2.44)
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
Broken libreoffice-common:amd64 Breaks on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (< 1:6.4.2~rc1)
Broken libreoffice-core:amd64 Depends on ure:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 6.1.1~)
Broken gnome-session-common:amd64 Breaks on eog:amd64 < 3.28.1-1 | 3.36.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 3.36.0)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken eog:amd64 Depends on librsvg2-2:amd64 < 2.40.20-2ubuntu0.2 | 2.48.7-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 2.44)
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
Broken libreoffice-common:amd64 Breaks on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (< 1:6.4.2~rc1)
Broken libreoffice-core:amd64 Depends on ure:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 6.1.1~)
Broken gnome-session-common:amd64 Breaks on eog:amd64 < 3.28.1-1 | 3.36.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 3.36.0)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken eog:amd64 Depends on librsvg2-2:amd64 < 2.40.20-2ubuntu0.2 | 2.48.7-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 2.44)
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
Broken libreoffice-common:amd64 Breaks on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (< 1:6.4.2~rc1)
Broken libreoffice-core:amd64 Depends on ure:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 6.1.1~)
Broken gnome-session-common:amd64 Breaks on eog:amd64 < 3.28.1-1 | 3.36.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 3.36.0)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken eog:amd64 Depends on librsvg2-2:amd64 < 2.40.20-2ubuntu0.2 | 2.48.7-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 2.44)
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
Broken libreoffice-common:amd64 Breaks on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (< 1:6.4.2~rc1)
Broken libreoffice-core:amd64 Depends on ure:amd64 < 6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 | 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 6.1.1~)
Broken gnome-session-common:amd64 Breaks on eog:amd64 < 3.28.1-1 | 3.36.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 3.36.0)
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
Broken eog:amd64 Depends on librsvg2-2:amd64 < 2.40.20-2ubuntu0.2 | 2.48.7-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 @ii umH > (>= 2.44)
```

Do I have to delete all these packages individually? Or there is some other shortcut?

Comment: I would try this over here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/

Comment: I tried the commands listed there. None of them really fix the broken packages.

Comment: I've used Synaptic Package Manager. It has worked for me. You'll have to install it. Then go here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto          Scroll down to Troubleshooting; then right under that, How to fix broken packages.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you find an answer to your question?